# How to invoke formatter programmatically in Xtext and get output string

Tags: xtext

Instead of calling save on resource I would like to convert model to string programmatically.
I have already implemented formatter and tests for it so I would like to reuse it.

Is it possible, and if possible how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Inject
    private Provider<ResourceSet> rsp;
    
    @Inject
    private ISerializer ser;

    ...

    ResourceSet rs = rsp.get();
    Resource r = rs.createResource(URI.createURI("dummy.mydsl"));
    r.getContents().add(myModel);
    System.out.println(ser.serialize(myModel, SaveOptions.newBuilder().format().getOptions());
```